# Magento theme mysteriously stops loading upon disabling (and then renabling) store view

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been banging my head over the last day or so over a VERY WIERD issue I'm encountering with my Magento 1.9 site. All was working fine until I decided to add another language to the store (while disabling one of the languages already present). What I did was follow the same process I used to set up the language i.e. go to store view, and simply "disable" the language I did not want in the language selector drop down.

However, immediately after I did this, the theme I'm using stopped loading correctly. And no matter what I do (renable etc), it simply won't load any more. This is ALL I did BTW - I did NOT modify any other settings, code etc. . .

Is there something I'm missing here? Any input would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you tried to clean the cache? Any external cache?
2. Please check the other scopes. Perhaps you changed it.